# How to not pop validations on partial view load?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view which contains a list of elements, to which i add a new element without limit, but when i add a field. It pops the validation for all the other fields of the list.

For example if i leave a field empty and call the controller and get the partial view back, the required error is poped for that field.

How can i avoid this case and pop validations only if they were poped before the post?

The id=5 is just for test purposes

I have a call to the controller like this

```
public ActionResult AddDestination(List<Destination> model)
    {
        model.Add(new Destination(){id = 5});

        return PartialView("_FieldDestination", model);
    }
```

AJAX Call:

```
function addField(event) {
    debugger;
    event.preventDefault();

    var model = $("#multipleDestinations:input").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("AddDestination", "Controller")',
        data: model,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            $("#multipleDestinations").html(data);
        }
        , error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
            console.log(xhr.statusText);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(error);}
    });

    }
```

Comment: Use a ViewModel (a class) that has only the fields that the user has to fill in, nothing else.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that wouldn't work since they both contains the same property, it is needed